# Binding DataGrid to DataView of DataTable doesn't update new columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable, dataview

I have a DataTable that I create rows and columns for from another part of the program. I bind the default DataView of this DataTable to a DataGrid. I update my DataTable in the following format:

1: Add three Columns to the DataTable

2: Add 20 rows of data at a time to the DataTable in the previously create columns.

3: Keep adding data for 1000 rows.

This works correctly. So next I call my UpdateTable method with new data that causes three additional columns to be created and then fill in data for these columns starting at row one through 1000. The DataTable is updated properly, but the DataGrid doesn't show the newly added columns.

What could be the reason that binding works fine when rows are being updated, but when I add additional columns binding fails?

I left out the DataTable update code for brevity.I am certain that this works as designed.

FYI: This same code works flawlessly with a third party DataGrid, but I would rather use the Microsoft DataGrid.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding View}"/>
```

VM:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DataTable table = new DataTable();

         public DataTable Table
        {
            get
            {
                return table;
            }

            set
            {
                table = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Table");
            }
        }

        public DataView View
        {
            get
            {
                return table.DefaultView;
            }            
        }

        public UpdateTable(UpdateData x)
        {
          //Algorithm to update the DataTable based on received data
          //Rows are dynamically being added and columns are dynamically being added
          onPropertyChanged("Table");
          onPropertyChanged("View");
        }

...
```

Comment: try raising a PropertyChanged("View") when you add more columns. That should make datagrid refresh it's ItemsSource and re-create columns.

Comment: I fire that property when I add Rows and Columns in the DataTable.

Comment: `null` the table and give it a `new` one.